# Get the unique element in a double array - Java

Tags: java, arrays

How do I get the element that appears once in a double array? Below is what I have tried, and the execution time is unacceptable. This will be ran against very huge arrays. There can only be one unique element.

```
public static double getUnique(double arr[]) {
    double res = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        res = arr[i];
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
            if (res == arr[j]){
                count ++;
            }
            if(j == arr.length - 1){
                if(count == 1){
                    return res;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Use a HashMap to count the occurrences.

Comment: Or sort the array and find the element which have distinct neighbors. It's O(n log(n)) and not O(n), but it requires no boxing, no entry allocations, and uses less memory, so maybe it's faster. You'd have to measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using streams:

If you are sure that there is always one unique element:

```
public static double getUnique(double arr[]) {
    return  Arrays.stream(arr).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet().stream().filter(e->e.getValue() == 1).findFirst().get().getKey();
}
```

Else return a default value using:

```
public static double getUnique2(double arr[]) {
    return  Arrays.stream(arr).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet().stream().filter(e->e.getValue() == 1)
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey).findFirst().orElse(-1.);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, this will count all doubles in a `HashMap` and return the first `double` of which the occurance is `1`:

```
public static double getUniqueMine(double arr[]) {
    // Keep track of the occurances of doubles
    HashMap<Double, Integer> doubleOccurances = new HashMap<>();

    // Loop through all doubles
    for(double d : arr) {
        // Increment double count
        doubleOccurances.merge(d, 1, Integer::sum);
    }

    // Return the first item where the count is 1
    for(Entry<Double, Integer> values : doubleOccurances.entrySet()) {
        if(values.getValue() == 1) {
            return values.getKey();
        }
    }

    return 0.0;
}
```

Comment: It should really throw an exception, or return an OptionalDouble, rather than returning a valid, but incorrect value 0.0. Also, the for loop body can be replaced by `doubleOccurances.merge(d, 1, Integer::sum);` (which is shorter and more efficient)

Comment: @JBNizet Agreed but the original question also returned `0.0` when there's no value found, so I stuck to that.

Comment: True that. I'll leave this comment there for the OP then.

Comment: You are right. It should throw an exception or return an OptionalDouble. I appreciate your quick response.